# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined slideshow

Tags: javascript

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this slideshow to work. I have to make an external Javascript file. I am very confused because I don't know js very well at all. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var numImages = 3;
var images = [];
for (var i = 0; i < numImages; ++i) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = 'baby' + (i + 1) + '.jpg';
    images.push(image);
}

var step = 0;
function slideit() {
    if (! document.images) {
        return;
    }
    document.images.slide.src = images[step].src;
    step = (step + 1) % numImages;
}
setInterval(slideit, 2500);
```

Comment: 1. Is there an `img` element on the page with `id="slide"`? 2. Is the JS running _after_ the document has been fully parsed?

Comment: There is now. And the JS is running after the document is parsed. It works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Unless this somewhere in your HTML ...

```
<img id="slide">
```

Then this will be is `undefined` ...

```
document.images.slide
```

Therefore ...

```
document.images.slide.src = ...
```

Explains ...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined
```

---

Here's a simplified piece of code that you can run and see it work

```js
var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=A',
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=B',
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=C'
]

function slideIt(elem, i, images) {
  elem.src = images[i % images.length]
  setTimeout(slideIt, 1000, elem, i+1, images)
}

slideIt(document.querySelector('#slideshow'), 0, images)
```

```html
<img id="slideshow">
```

---

In your original code, you were preloading the images. I've made a small adaptation below to preload images first before initializing the slider.

```js
var images = [
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=A',
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=B',
  'http://placehold.it/200?text=C'
]

function slideIt(elem, i, images) {
  elem.src = images[i % images.length].src
  setTimeout(slideIt, 1000, elem, i+1, images)
}

function imagep(src) {
  return new Promise(function(pass,fail) {
    var i = new Image()
    i.src = src
    i.onload = function(event) { pass(i) }
  })
}

Promise.all(images.map(imagep)).then(function(imgs) {
  slideIt(document.querySelector('#slideshow'), 0, imgs)
})
```

```html
<img id="slideshow">
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked! I have been searching and searching but could not find anything. So simple.